# Separate distinct values in to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

Hi all I am quite new to SQL. I have a table (TABLE1) with two columns as below

```
Name age
--------
jim  18
jim  21
dave 18
dave 18
john 23
john 41
```

I need to create a view in SSMS which lists distinct ages for each name in a separate column as below

```
Jim  Dave  John
---------------
18   18     23
21          41
```

I have tried a sub query like

`SELECT DISTINCT AGE FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = JIM`

But I encountered a sub query cannot return more than one value.

Comment: And if the row (Steve, 17) later is inserted into table1, do you suddenly want a Steve column too?

Comment: Yes that would be great and future proof the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` & do aggregation :

```
select max(case when name = 'jim' then age end) as jim,
       max(case when name = 'dave' then age end) as dave,
       max(case when name = 'john' then age end) as john
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by age) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by seq;
```

Comment: As suggested by @jarlh17 above, how could i edit this statement so any new names added to the table would automatically be included ?

Comment: also i there was a third column Gender how can i add where gender = male ? by adding a where clause at the end of the above statement it includes the records with gender = female as a NULL

Comment: @Eskifan. . . You can include  `where` clause in sub-query. If you have a more names then you probably need Dynamic Query.